# Why does mypy not consider a class as iterable if it has __len__ and __getitem__ but no __iter__

Tags: python, mypy

I was playing around with `mypy` and some basic iteration in Python and wrote the below code base:

```
from typing import Iterator
from datetime import date, timedelta

class DateIterator:
    def __init__(self, start_date, end_date):
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self._total_dates = self._get_all_dates()

    def _get_all_dates(self) -> Iterator[date]:
        current_day = self.start_date
        while current_day <= self.end_date:
            yield current_day
            current_day += timedelta(days=1)

    def __len__(self):
        print("Calling the len function...")
        return len(self._total_dates)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print(f"Calling getitem with value of index as {index}")
        return self._total_dates[index]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    date_iterator = DateIterator(date(2019, 1, 1), date(2019, 1, 15))
    for new_date in date_iterator:
        print(new_date)

    date_str = ",".join([str(new_date) for new_date in date_iterator])
    print(date_str)

    print(f"Checking the length of the collection {len(date_iterator)}")

    print(f"Checking if indexing works : {date_iterator[4]}")
```

Now to also play around with `mypy` i got the below issues:

```
iterator_test_with_getitem.py:30: error: Cannot assign to a type
iterator_test_with_getitem.py:30: error: "DateIterator" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)
iterator_test_with_getitem.py:33: error: "DateIterator" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Can someone please guide me that if an object is iterable with the addition of `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods then why is `mypy` complaining when it has no `iter` method

Also can someone please tell me what the issue with line 30 is . I don't find any logical explanation of that error as well.

Comment: I don't see the "Cannot assign to a type" error when I run mypy on this code. I suspect that came from a version of the code where you did `for date in date_iterator` instead of `for new_date in date_iterator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mypy -- and PEP 484 type checkers in general -- define an iterable to be any class that defines the `__iter__` method. You can see the exact definition of the Iterable type in Typeshed, the collection of type hints for the standard library: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi#L146

The reason why Iterable is defined in this way and excludes types that only define `__getitem__` and `__len__` is because:

1. The only way to say that a type must either implement `__iter__` or implement `__getitem__/__len__` is to use a Union -- and defining Iterable to be a union complicates life a bit for anybody who wants to make extensive use of the Iterable type in their own code.
2. Conversely, it's trivial for a class that defines `__getitem__` and `__len__` to define their own `__iter__` method. For example, you could do something as simple as this:

   ```
   def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[date]:
       for i in range(len(self)):
           yield self[i]
   ```

   Or alternatively, something like this (assuming you fixed your constructor so `self._total_dates` is a list, not a generator):

   ```
   def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[date]:
       return iter(self._total_dates)
   ```

So, given this cost-benefit tradeoff, it makes sense to define Iterable to just be any object that implements `__iter__`. It's not much of a burden for people who are defining custom classes and simplifies life for people who want to write functions manipulating iterables.

Comment: Defining your own iterator with range/len and indexing is [slower](https://ideone.com/3Of2V3) than letting the default handle it, though.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica -- this depends on how you implement `__iter__`. It's true that the first version I provided is slower since all it's doing is reimplementing what Python would have done under the hood, just in Python instead of C. However, anything similar to the second will be faster than both alternatives: since we're directly accessing the underlying fields and returning a generator, we get to skip the overhead of having to constantly call the `__getitem__` function. For example, see https://ideone.com/8WE5Ve -- the last four runs are all on par with or faster than the first.