# How can I tell mypy that __len__ + __getitem__ makes an object iterable?

Tags: python, mypy

Within PyPDF2, there is a class [`ConvertFunctionsToVirtualList`](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/blob/main/PyPDF2/utils.py#L158-L179) which basically works like this:

### MVCE

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Union


class _VirtualList:
    def __init__(
        self,
        length_function: Callable[[], int],
        get_function: Callable[[int], Any],
    ) -> None:
        self.length_function = length_function
        self.get_function = get_function

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.length_function()

    def __getitem__(self, index: Union[int, slice]) -> Any:
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            indices = range(*index.indices(len(self)))
            cls = type(self)
            return cls(indices.__len__, lambda idx: self[indices[idx]])
        if not isinstance(index, int):
            raise TypeError("sequence indices must be integers")
        len_self = len(self)
        if index < 0:
            # support negative indexes
            index = len_self + index
        if index < 0 or index >= len_self:
            raise IndexError("sequence index out of range")
        return self.get_function(index)


class Doc:
    def __init__(self, stream: str) -> None:
        self.stream = stream.split(" ")

    def get_nb_tokens(self):
        return len(self.stream)

    def get_token(self, index):
        return self.stream[index]

    @property
    def pages(self) -> _VirtualList:
        """
        Read-only property that emulates a list based upon the
        :meth:`getNumPages()<PdfFileReader.getNumPages>` and
        :meth:`getPage()<PdfFileReader.getPage>` methods.
        """
        return _VirtualList(self.get_nb_tokens, self.get_token)


doc = Doc("ab cde asdfe e")
for x in doc.pages:
    print(x)
```

### The problem

When I run mypy on this file, it tells me:

> example.py:52: error: "_VirtualList" has no attribute "**iter**" (not iterable)

However, when I run the Program with Python 3.10.2, it works just fine. Is this a bug in mypy? Is there a way to let mypy know that this iterable?

Comment: Well... you could probably add `def __iter__(self): return self`?

Comment: does `from collections.abc import Sequence`, and `class _VirtualList(Sequence):` help? Or perhaps `typing.Sequence`?

Comment: That's a long MCVE... All you need is a class with `__getitem__`, you can do that in 10 lines.

Comment: Related: [Why does mypy not consider a class as iterable if it has `__len__` and `__getitem__` but no `__iter__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61712618/why-does-mypy-not-consider-a-class-as-iterable-if-it-has-len-and-getitem)

Comment: @azro "How do I change the behavior of mypy?" is not the same question as "Why does mypy behave like this?"

Comment: @Aran-Fey the accepted answer explains how to solve the issue

Comment: @azro Does it? Are you referring to the part where it says "it's trivial for a class [...] to define their own `__iter__` method"? Since the class is defined in a 3rd-party module, OP can't exactly add an `__iter__` method to it.

Comment: Since I don't have a better answer, I'll compromise and (begrudgingly) leave the question closed. But if someone wants to post an actual answer, let me know and I'll reopen it.

Comment: If Doc is in your code, then add a class that implements _VirtualList, so you can add the fixes given in the duplicate link, keep the existing methods, and it' should be ok